# C++ SDL How to undo a BlitSurface

Tags: c++, sdl

I have used SDL to display an image:

```
SDL_BlitSurface(sprite, NULL, screen, NULL);
```

My question is: Is it possible to remove the image from the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, no. `SDL_BlitSurface()` overwrites (a subset of) the contents of the destination surface, essentially the same as an assignment to an array of pixel data. One solution is to redraw the entire screen every frame, first clearing with:

```
SDL_FillRect(screen, 0, SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, r, g, b));
```

For better performance, you could keep track of which regions on the screen are “dirty” and need to be repainted each frame, and only repaint those regions. SDL offers some functions for doing that (`SDL_UpdateRect()` and `SDL_UpdateRects()`) but I wouldn’t bother unless rendering speed becomes a serious issue. Most SDL applications seem to be able to do 30–50 frames per second; beyond that, you’ll want to look at OpenGL.